# See Console for Flask Web-Page at Pythonanywhere

Tags: console, pythonanywhere

I launched a simple Web-Page with FLASK on Pythonanywhere.com like beneath.
Now I would like to see the GET and POST requests from the users, like as if I would see it in a console if I launch a local webserver with `python flask_app.py`. But in pythonanywhere I can't execute it like this from the console.

Is there an other way for seeing the actual console of my webpage ?

Thank you

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
    username="***",
    password="***",
    hostname="**",
    databasename="**$comments",
)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Comment(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "comments"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(4096))

comments = []

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("main_page.html", comments=Comment.query.all())

    comment = Comment(content=request.form["contents"])
    db.session.add(comment)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Answer (score 1):

All accesses are logged to your access log. There is a link on the web app tab.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant !